# Sample Rest API call using typescript in Visual studio OfficeJS

Tags: office-js

We are trying to make API call in OFfice JS using typescript for Excel -addin.Can you please provide some example.

We tried using Promise but getting error 'Promise only refers to a Type but is being used value here'

Comment: could you please post your code so we can see what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the sample code for Excel in the [Script Lab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab) tool are in TypeScript, so you'll find lots of examples there.